# How to get the earliest date for the material code from multiple condition

Tags: excel-formula

How to get the earliest date for the same material code from the category (Pull, Push, Push-M, Pull-M). Secondly , return blank if no matching category. Can anyone help to guide the appropriate formula to use by refer from the sample data image.

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LysBh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$22:$B$36, MATCH(F22,$A$22:$A$36,0)),"")
```

but be careful about cell formatting in G.

With filtering for PU in the Category:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$22:$B$36, MATCH(F22,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("pu*",$C$22:$C$36)),$A$22:$A$36),0)),"")
```

Comment: Thanks for participate. I want to return the earliest date from Pull, Push, Pull-M and Push-M....

Comment: Sure - but where will the criteria "Pull, Push, Push-M, Pull-M" be placed in your sheet? It is not shown. Is it that you want to filter the data and only show dates that have one of these words in the category?  Do you need to show earliest dates for each category like a Pivot table with category as columns and materials as rows that delivers MIN of date?

Comment: Sorry my question may not that clear.  yes , I want the column G to auto populate the earliest date from one "Pull, Push, Push-M, Pull-M" of the category under the same material code.

Comment: OK - I am still not entirely sure I understand, but I will add a FILTER to the formula above that looks for "Pu" as this is a quick way to remove any rows that do not contain "Pull, Push, Push-M, Pull-M".  However, the "..." tells me that there are probably more such conditions, so it will not pick those up.

Comment: It's worked!!!! I have been scratching out my head how to return the earliest date from the selected "pu" by matching up the same material code. Finally I can proceed to the next step now....Appreciated!

Comment: I have another question. For example, Column G return earliest date from one of the category "POmemo and In transit"...I think should be using Index+Match+IF but I not sure how to write it...could you able to help this as well?

Comment: Cool - glad it worked. Let me take a look, but it will be later - loaded with meetings today.

Comment: OK - so here is a quick formula for POmemo and In transit: `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$22:$B$36, MATCH(F22,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("in*",$C$22:$C$36))+ISNUMBER(SEARCH("po*",$C$22:$C$36)),$A$22:$A$36),0)),"")`. You can see how this is just adding the conditions `ISNUMBER(SEARCH("in*",$C$22:$C$36))+ISNUMBER(SEARCH("po*",$C$22:$C$36))`. Adding is the same as say "or" whereas multiplying is the same as saying "and". Note that this can start to slow your spreadsheet down, so I am not sure it is the most efficient solution, but it is easy to implement and I cannot think of better off the top of my head. :-)

Comment: Perhaps a little safer version would be : `ISNUMBER(SEARCH("In transit",$C$22:$C$36))+ISNUMBER(SEARCH("POmemo",$C$22:$C$36))` because it is not using wildcards. It may run faster too. The use of "pu*" was a quick way to get both of the PU conditions without using + (or) that would repeat the search operation. If there is nothing unique and in common, such as with POmemo and In transit, you have to do multiple searches.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your kindness support on the problem that I facing. I'm trying your formula ...really "WOW"....almost the end to finalize the report layout. Thanks alot....